Error linking C++ GMP to CMake-built Executable
I am working on a project that requires manipulation of large floating point numbers and integers, just like Python. I sought for many libraries and chose GMP. I downloaded and unzipped the GMP source file (which is gmp-6.3.0 in my Downloads folder). Then, I installed GMP with
$ ./configure --enable-cxx --bindir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/bin --sbindir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/sbin --libexecdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/sysconf --sharedstatedir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/sharedstate --localstatedir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/localstate --libdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/lib --includedir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/include --oldincludedir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/oldinclude --datarootdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/dataroot --datadir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/data --infodir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/info --localedir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/locale --mandir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/man --docdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/doc --htmldir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/html --dvidir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/dvi --pdfdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/pdf --psdir=/Users/USER/Downloads/gmp-6.3.0/build/ps
...
$ make
...
$ make check
...  # all passes
$ make install
...

Then, I have created the following files and directories:
+ bin
|--- + darwin
|--- + linux
|--- + win32
+ build
|--- + gcc
|--- + llvm
|--- |--- (Miscellaneous build files)
|--- + mingw
+ include
+ installer
+ lib
|--- + darwin
|--- |--- + include
|--- |--- |--- + mpf
|--- |--- |--- |--- - fits_s.h
|--- |--- |--- |--- - fits_u.h
|--- |--- |--- + mpn
|--- |--- |--- |--- - jacobitab.h
|--- |--- |--- |--- - perfsqr.h
|--- |--- |--- + mpz
|--- |--- |--- |--- - aors_ui.h
|--- |--- |--- |--- - airs.h
|--- |--- |--- |--- - fits_s.h
|--- |--- |--- |--- - mul_i.h
|--- |--- |--- + rand
|--- |--- |--- |--- - randmt.h
|--- |--- |--- + tune
|--- |--- |--- |--- - speed.h
|--- |--- |--- - asl.h
|--- |--- |--- - config.h
|--- |--- |--- - fac_table.h
|--- |--- |--- - fib_table.h
|--- |--- |--- - gmp-impl.h
|--- |--- |--- - gmp.h
|--- |--- |--- - gmpxx.h
|--- |--- |--- - longlong.h
|--- |--- |--- - mp_bases.h
|--- |--- |--- - sieve_table.h
|--- |--- |--- - trialdivtab.h
|--- |--- + pkgconfig
|--- |--- |--- - gmp.pc
|--- |--- |--- - gmpxx.pc
|--- |--- - libgmpxx.4.dylib
|--- |--- - libgmpxx.a
|--- |--- - libgmpxx.la
|--- + linux
|--- + win32
+ libexec
+ src
|--- - CMakeLists.txt
|--- - main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

The Minimal Reproductive Example (MRE) content of the src/main.cpp would be:
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpz_class x("7612058254738945");
    mpz_class y("9263591128439081");
    std::cout << x * y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

And the MRE content of ./CMakeLists.txt would be (merged the content of src/CMakeLists.txt into this file already):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
project(BigNumProject LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.7.0)

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Windows")
    set(OS_IN_USE "win32")
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
    set(OS_IN_USE "linux")
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Darwin")
    set(OS_IN_USE "darwin")
endif()

set(GMP_HEADERS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/gmp/${OS_IN_USE}/include")

if (${OS_IN_USE} STREQUAL "darwin")
    set(GMP_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/gmp/darwin/libgmpxx.4.dylib")
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${GMP_HEADERS})

add_executable(
    BigNumProject
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(BigNumProject PRIVATE ${GMP_LIBRARY})

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS BigNumProject
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

The CMake generation of Makefile exits with code 0 and with no errors:
[cmake] Running /Users/USER/Qt/Tools/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -S /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject -B /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/build/llvm in /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/build/llvm.
[cmake] -- Setting GMP library binaries to .
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.2s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/build/llvm
[cmake] 
[cmake] Elapsed time: 00:00.

However, the linker and the compiler went mad:
"/Users/USER/Qt/Tools/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake" --build /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/build/llvm --target all
[1/1 1.3/sec] Linking CXX executable /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/bin/darwin/BigNumProject
FAILED: /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/bin/darwin/BigNumProject 
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/BigNumProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o -o /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/bin/darwin/BigNumProject  /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/lib/gmp/darwin/libgmpxx.a && :
ld: Undefined symbols:
  ___gmp_allocate_func, referenced from:
      __gmp_doprnt_integer_ostream(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, doprnt_params_t*, char*) in libgmpxx.a[9](osdoprnti.o)
  ___gmp_asprintf_final, referenced from:
      __gmp_doprnt_integer_ostream(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, doprnt_params_t*, char*) in libgmpxx.a[9](osdoprnti.o)
  ___gmp_asprintf_memory, referenced from:
      ___gmp_asprintf_funs_noformat in libgmpxx.a[10](osfuns.o)
  ___gmp_asprintf_reps, referenced from:
      ___gmp_asprintf_funs_noformat in libgmpxx.a[10](osfuns.o)
  ___gmp_doprnt_integer, referenced from:
      __gmp_doprnt_integer_ostream(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, doprnt_params_t*, char*) in libgmpxx.a[9](osdoprnti.o)
  ___gmp_free_func, referenced from:
      __gmp_doprnt_integer_ostream(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, doprnt_params_t*, char*) in libgmpxx.a[9](osdoprnti.o)
  ___gmpz_clear, referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
      ...
  ___gmpz_get_str, referenced from:
      operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, __mpz_struct const*) in libgmpxx.a[13](osmpz.o)
  ___gmpz_init, referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  ___gmpz_init_set_str, referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
  ___gmpz_mul, referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Even if I change the GMP_LIBRARY from `"libgmpxx.4.dylib" to "libgmpxx.a" or "libgmpxx.la", this error still exists and prevents the program to finish building.
As you could see already, I am using macOS Ventura. It says "Qt" because I am using Qt Creator as an IDE, but in fact I am not using any part of Qt.
By the way, after reviewing those similar questions on StackOverflow and CMake forum, they are not suitable for me. Either they are using findPackage instead of adding libraries from raw sources; or they are using a completely irrelevant mechanism.
Any help will be appreciated. Comment me for more information or amendments. Thanks very much in advance.

Are you sure GMP_LIBRARY has been set? What's the compiler command? What's the full compiler output? Are you sure you've built gmp with the same architecture as your application? Is there a reason you're not using find_package or pkg_check_modules?

@Alan Birtles 1. Yes, [cmake] -- Setting GMP library binaries to /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/lib/gmp/darwin/libgmpxx.a. from my message(STATUS); 2. The compiler commands, flags is is cmake --build /Users/USER/Projects/BigNumProject/build/llvm --target all; 3. Edited; 4. I don't use them because I want to use the bound library, just like I've done with QScintilla with my editor project; 5. Yes, same architecture (intel x86_64). Guaranteed.

You need to link to gmp to, gmpxx is just the c++ wrapper
